Azure Key Vault Signature Format
I have this snippet on my local machine (dotnet 8.0) which is working fine.
using System.Security.Cryptography;

using (ECDsa ecdsa = ECDsa.Create(ECCurve.NamedCurves.nistP256))
{
    
    string input = "some base64 encoded data";
    byte[] data_bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(input);

    byte[] hash = SHA256.Create().ComputeHash(data_bytes);

    byte[] publicKeyBytes = ecdsa.ExportSubjectPublicKeyInfo();
    Console.WriteLine($"Public Key:\n{Convert.ToBase64String(publicKeyBytes)}\n");

    // Sign the hash using the Rfc3279DerSequence format
    byte[] signature_der = ecdsa.SignHash(hash, DSASignatureFormat.Rfc3279DerSequence);
    bool isValid_der = ecdsa.VerifyHash(hash, signature_der, DSASignatureFormat.Rfc3279DerSequence);
    Console.WriteLine($"Signature valid: {isValid_der}\n");
    string signature_b64_der = Convert.ToBase64String(signature_der);
    Console.WriteLine($"DER Signature:\n{signature_b64_der}\n");

    // Sign the hash using the IeeeP1363FixedFieldConcatenation format
    byte[] signature_ieee = ecdsa.SignHash(hash, DSASignatureFormat.IeeeP1363FixedFieldConcatenation);
    bool isValid_ieee = ecdsa.VerifyHash(hash, signature_ieee, DSASignatureFormat.IeeeP1363FixedFieldConcatenation);
    Console.WriteLine($"Signature valid: {isValid_ieee}\n");
    string signature_b64_ieee = Convert.ToBase64String(signature_ieee);
    Console.WriteLine($"IEEE Signature:\n{signature_b64_ieee}\n");
}

I want to implement the same logic, but this time I want to use Azure Key vault REST APIs to sign and verify same kind of data. I aimed for this approach so I can rotate keys regularly.
The signature return by Azure Key Vault seems to be returned as IEEE P1363 format only and I did not find a way to return the RFC 3279 DER Sequence format.
My question: Is there a way to obtain from Azure Key Vault signature in a different format, and of course to be able to verify that signature?
I've tried to use the CryptographyClient.SignAsync, but again it returns only the IEEE P1363 format, and I want the other format too (if possible).

Do you get any error?

@Rukmini: I do not get errors. I did not find a way to return both formats of the signature. It seems that Azure Key Vault returns only this format IEEE P1363 (and I can get the signature and verify it successfully).
My goal here is to get the signature in the RFC 3279 DER Sequence format too.

I generated EC key type with P-256 Elliptic curve:


Convert from IEEE P1363 to DER.
From Azure Key Vault retrieve the IEEE P1363 signature.
Use ConvertIeeeP1363ToDer function to convert it to DER.
Use ECDsa.VerifyHash to verify the DER-formatted signature.

Make use of below code:
public class AzureKeyVaultECDSASignature
{
    private static string keyVaultUrl = "https://rrruuukkk.vault.azure.net/";
    private static string keyName = "myECDSAKey";

    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var client = new KeyClient(new Uri(keyVaultUrl), new DefaultAzureCredential());

        var key = await client.GetKeyAsync(keyName);
        var keyId = key.Value.Id;
        var cryptoClient = new CryptographyClient(keyId, new DefaultAzureCredential());

        string message = "Hello, Azure Key Vault!";
        byte[] messageHash = SHA256.HashData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message));

        byte[] ieeeSignature = await SignMessageAsync(cryptoClient, messageHash);
        Console.WriteLine("IEEE P1363 Signature (Base64): " + Convert.ToBase64String(ieeeSignature));

        byte[] derSignature = ConvertIeeeP1363ToDer(ieeeSignature);
        Console.WriteLine("DER Signature (Base64): " + Convert.ToBase64String(derSignature));

        bool isValid = await VerifySignatureAsync(messageHash, derSignature);
        Console.WriteLine($"Signature valid in DER format: {isValid}");
    }

    private static async Task<byte[]> SignMessageAsync(CryptographyClient cryptoClient, byte[] messageHash)
    { 
        var signResult = await cryptoClient.SignAsync(SignatureAlgorithm.ES256, messageHash);
        return signResult.Signature;
    }

    private static async Task<bool> VerifySignatureAsync(byte[] hash, byte[] derSignature)
    {
        var client = new KeyClient(new Uri(keyVaultUrl), new DefaultAzureCredential());
        var key = await client.GetKeyAsync(keyName);
        var jsonWebKey = key.Value.Key;

        if (jsonWebKey.X != null && jsonWebKey.Y != null)
        {
            using (ECDsa ecdsa = ECDsa.Create(ECCurve.NamedCurves.nistP256))
            {
                ecdsa.ImportParameters(new ECParameters
                {
                    Curve = ECCurve.NamedCurves.nistP256,
                    Q = new ECPoint
                    {
                        X = jsonWebKey.X,
                        Y = jsonWebKey.Y
                    }
                });

                // Verify the signature
                return ecdsa.VerifyHash(hash, derSignature, DSASignatureFormat.Rfc3279DerSequence);
            }
        }

        throw new InvalidOperationException("Invalid public key in the key vault.");
    }

    // Method to convert IEEE P1363 signature to DER sequence format
    private static byte[] ConvertIeeeP1363ToDer(byte[] ieeeSignature)
    {
        if (ieeeSignature.Length % 2 != 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Invalid IEEE P1363 signature length");
        }

        int halfLength = ieeeSignature.Length / 2;
        byte[] r = new byte[halfLength];
        byte[] s = new byte[halfLength];

        Array.Copy(ieeeSignature, 0, r, 0, halfLength);
        Array.Copy(ieeeSignature, halfLength, s, 0, halfLength);

        var writer = new AsnWriter(AsnEncodingRules.DER);
        writer.PushSequence();
        writer.WriteInteger(r);
        writer.WriteInteger(s);
        writer.PopSequence();

        return writer.Encode();
    }
}



given your example I am able to convert the signature and validate the signature successfully in C#, but if I were to try and verify the exact signature with openssl the signature verification fails. I made sure I have the proper public key (downloaded from Az KeyVault as *.pem), I made sure the digest is the same (the only difference I saw, is that in C# I get all characters in uppercase where in openssl they are lowercase, but the digest is the same), so I assume is still something related to the converted signature. Any leads?

Please post a new question with details and paste the link here will help you:)

I've posted a new question
Verifying a signature with OpenSSL

Sure will check
